# Why is my SHA-1 function displaying the same output for both files in C#?

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, md5

I'm able to display the two different MD5 values of two different files selected, however, the SHA-1 function displays the exact same value for both of them. Why is that?

I'm not a great programmer so I don't know if this code is particularly good or not but any help or advice would be much appreciated.

```
{

System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 md5 = System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1 sha1 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1.Create();

FileStream file1 = new FileStream(lblBrowse1.Text, FileMode.Open);
FileStream file2 = new FileStream(lblBrowse2.Text, FileMode.Open);


byte[] hash1 = md5.ComputeHash(file1);
byte[] hash2 = md5.ComputeHash(file2);
byte[] hash3 = sha1.ComputeHash(file1);
byte[] hash4 = sha1.ComputeHash(file2);

file1.Close();
file2.Close();


textBox1.Text = BitConverter.ToString(hash1).Replace("-", "");
textBox2.Text = BitConverter.ToString(hash2).Replace("-", "");
textBox6.Text = BitConverter.ToString(hash3).Replace("-", "");
textBox7.Text = BitConverter.ToString(hash4).Replace("-", "");



if (textBox1.Text == textBox2.Text)
   {
MessageBox.Show("These two files are identical.");
   }
else
   {
MessageBox.Show("These two files are different.");
   }
```

Comment: Although highly unlikely, it's not true to say that a matching hash equates to matching data. Hashes do collide so if hashes match, you should take secondary measures to ensure matching data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the MD5 hash has moved the stream to EOF for both file1 and file2. You need to rewind the streams back before reusing them:

```
byte[] hash1 = md5.ComputeHash(file1);
byte[] hash2 = md5.ComputeHash(file2);

file1.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
file2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

byte[] hash3 = sha1.ComputeHash(file1);
byte[] hash4 = sha1.ComputeHash(file2);
```

Comment: I had the same issue trying to calculate checksums for a file by first using MD5 and then SHA1, SHA256, etc. The MD5 hash was always correct since it was first, and then the subsequent SHA algorithms produced the exact same incorrect output each time and I wondered what was going on!

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, the SHA-1 hash you're seeing is that of the *empty string*:

```
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```

This is because the `FileStream` has already been read all the way to the end, during the previous calculation of the MD5 hash.

To re-use the `FileStream`s, you should "rewind" them, like this:

```
file1.Position = 0;
```